# Polymer extend input

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, web-component

I'm pretty new to Polymer, so apologies if I'm doing something stupid, but this won't work properly.

```
<polymer-element name="x-input" extends="input" noscript>
  <template>
    <style>
        :host {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 10px;
            display: inline-block;
        }
    </style>
  </template>
</polymer-element>

<!-- Using x-input -->
<input is="x-input" />
```

I can style it, but for some reason I cannot type in it. Any ideas?

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t48phqdz/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not an expert either, but did you consider doing it the same way as in `core-input`? https://github.com/Polymer/core-input/blob/master/core-input.html

I did an update in your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kreide/t48phqdz/2/

Here is also a snippet:

```html
<script src="http://www.polymer-project.org/polymer.min.js"></script>
<polymer-element name="x-input" extends="input" noscript>
    <style>
        input[is=x-input] {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 10px;
            display: inline-block;
        }
    </style>
</polymer-element>
<input is="x-input"></input>
```

PS: may I ask you for the reason of extending input? If it is just about styling, I would suggest the use of `paper-input-decorator`.

Comment: I just came back to post the answer as I just discovered the problem, wish I checked back earlier now. I was styling inside the `<template>` tag, which seems so obvious when I look back now. You are correct, that's the way to do it. Thanks for answering.